# Write a batch file to repeatedly copy files

Tags: loops, batch-file, copy, repeat

I am trying to make a batch/script file that will repeatedly COPY a file from one location to another. I don't care if it overwrites the file or if it doesn't copy if the file exists. But I want a batch file that copies a file within a loop.

**How do I go about making a batch file to repeatedly copy a file?**

```
loop:
copy /y a.txt c:/b.txt
Goto loop
```

It runs once.

---

batch.bat:

```
rere:
copy /y c:\folder1\abc.txt c:\folder2\abc.txt
pause
goto rere
```

output when double-clicking batch.bat:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop> rere:
'rere:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\User\Desktop> copy /y c:\folder1\abc.txt c:\folder2\abc.txt
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Users\User\Desktop> pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Do you need the copy operation to happen at some specified interval of time or do you literally want it to happen continuously as fast as possible? What do you mean by "I don't care ... if it doesn't copy if the file exists"?

Comment: I'd like it to be as fast as possible. But at the same time I wonder if that would crash windows? Copy has 3 choices:  1) Copy and replace  2) Don't copy if it exists  3) Copy and rename the copy to filename(copy #)  


I do not care if it does the first 2

Comment: ...and what is your question?

Comment: How do I go about making a batch file to repeatedly copy a file?

Comment: There are many ways, perhaps too many; any preference of language? Platform? Restrictions on what you can use?

Comment: Preferably BATCH hence the the first part of my post "I am trying to make a batch/script file..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:loop
copy file1 file2
Goto loop
```

is how. See `goto /?` and `copy /?`.

Comment: 'loop:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: It's not `loop` its `:loop` See `goto /?`.

Comment: You use that in your batch file... see what cmd says.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code dude. 
 
Look at my post, I added a photo of my error message along with the code I used

Comment: You modified it yourself. `copy c:\windows\win.ini "c:\program files"` Note backslashes.

Comment: There is nothing from my post in your picture. Goto and a label (a string starting with a colon) need to be in a batch file.

Comment: I apologize, I am used to assembly language. In assembly it's label: in batch it's :label i forgot. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The reason rere is giving an error is because you should change `goto rere` to `goto :rere`. Read [This](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) it explains goto :eof which is essentially a loop.

Also check this code out

```
@echo on
:loop
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set source="%UserProfile%\Desktop\source\"
set target="%UserProfile%\Desktop\destination\
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir %source%\*.* /b /s') do (
set B=%%a
set C=!B:\=%random%!
set D=!C:~3,88!
copy "%%a" %target%\"!D!"
)
goto :loop
```

It copies the same file over and over again changing the file name every time in a loop. Try it out and give me some feedback, I want to improve it a bit.
It's quite a horrid little script XD

Answer (score 1):

A minor variation on Noodle's implementation (unfairly voted down):

```
@echo off
:loop
copy file1 file2
rem The 'timeout' line will wait for 1 sec between copy attempts
rem Remove the 'rem ' statement from the line to use this feature
rem timeout 1 > nul
goto loop
```

Note that Noodle's code works; you must be careful in copying the last instruction correctly.

Comment: Look at my post, I added a photo of my error message along with the code I used

Comment: It looks like you are just copying and pasting to the console. That will not work. You need to copy all the code into a text file, e.g. copyinf.bat, then run copyinf.bat from the console.

Comment: No sir, you are mistaken. I understand HOW to make a batch file. I need help with WHAT commands to use to make it work. See that code block? Yeah thats what is within my batch.bat

Answer (score 1):

This is how you copy a file in a loop without over writing the target file. 
This batch script creates files with unique names in the destination folder, like file1.txt, file2.txt etc.

```
@echo off
SET i=1
:loop
SET /A i=i+1
echo %i%
copy c:\test\abc.txt c:\test\file%i%.txt
Goto loop
```